# How to center a div horizontally only?

Tags: html, css

I wonder what's the best way to center a div horizontally only, basically it wouldn't matter the height only the width. I've seen so many examples around but they focused about horizontal and vertical alike, which I do not need neither want.

So lets say I have this:

```
<body>
<div id="layout">
    Content of my site here.
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Question title: "How to center a div vertically only?". Question body: "what's the best way to center a div horizontally only". Good luck with that.

Comment: You have asked two different questions. Your title asks for vertical alignment and your post asks for horizontal alignment. What do you want?

Comment: Search for `vertical align center` on SO, many answers such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048541/vertical-text-center-in-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vertical:**

For verticals, you must use something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

And just use this:

```
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This will remove paddings margins and list style. And you will have a vertical list. Now place it where you want!

**Horizontal:**

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Now for this there is just one more line in CSS:

```
ul li {
display: inline; // this is used to place elements in one line..
}
```

Others will be same!

This is all! Now you can place this list in your div. And it will work!

To position it, you can either use `position: absolute` for this you will require to use `position: relative` for the parent div. Or you can use `padding:` or `margin`. That's all that you would require!

Answer (score 0):

```
#layout {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

That will center `#layout` horizontally relative to the window, or it's parent, if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

It will center vertically

```
  #layout{position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-heightofDiv/2;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most appropriate way to do is using either

```
margin-top:
margin-bottom:

padding-top:
padding-bottom:
```

What to choose between margin and padding depends on your layout.
In your code, you can choose margin applied to

```
 <div id="layout">
```

or else you can set padding of the container of the

```
 <div id="layout">
```

(body in this case).